# Fake Stack Overflow in Google Search

Tags: support, spam

I came across a fake/scraped version of Stack Overflow when Googling.
[Here's a link (BE CAREFUL)](http://57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a.extratorrent.filespook.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk?page=2&sort=newest)

At first I thought it was just rogue Javascript popup ads that you guys might want to hear about but then my colleague pointed out that the site wasn't actually legitimate.

I've reported the site to Google is there anything else I should do?

It looks like it's scraping the real site as some of the results in the background are releveant to my original query, or is that just a coincidence?

EDIT: 
After further navigating the site it looks like the real site with adverts on the top of it.

Comment: No need to panic. SE are aware of the scrapers and doing what they can against them.